# How to use beautiful soup choose certain "Span" content

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="Ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
   <span>13586</span>
   <span>(</span>
   <span class="change_decrease">-6.5%</span>
   <span>)</span>
</div>

<div class="Ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
   <span>99492</span>
   <span>(</span>
   <span class="change_decrease">+1.4%</span>
   <span>)</span>
</div>
```

Above is my HTML. I only want the number 13586, 99492.

This is the code i am using.

```
TicketNumber= []
tickets_by_Lanuages = soup.select('div[class="tickets_by_language"]')[0]
ALLnum= tickets_by_Lanuages.findAll('span')
for p in ALLnum:
    TicketNumber.append(p.text)

It is printing out like it:
[
['13586',
 '(',
  '-6.4%',
   ')',
 '99492',
 '(',
 '+1.4%',
  ')']
```

how i can use beautiful soup select only the number ['13568','99492']

Comment: Please add also the code you've used to try things out.

Comment: number=[]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tickets_by_Lanuages = soup.select('div[class="tickets_by_language"]')[0]
number.append(tickets_by_Lanuages.select('div span'))

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS selector:

```
data = """<div class="Report_last_week report_table_right">
<span> 11232</span>
<span>(</span>
<span class="change_decrease">-6.2%</span>
</span>)</span>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('div span').text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
11232
```

If you want to be more specific, you can specify which classes has the `<div>` tag. The following code has the same effect:

```
print(soup.select_one('div.Report_last_week.report_table_right span').text.strip())
```

Comment: its printing out none. Sorry, Let me put the HTML here again.

Comment: @JulieHou The example I posted prints `1132`. Do you have other html that you parse?

Comment: <div class="Report_last_week report_table_right">
<span> 11232</span>
   <span>(</span> 
   <span class="change_decrease">-6.2%</span>
   </span>)</span>
</div>

Comment: they are all under same div class and i only want to print out the first span. I tried your solution. It only print out none.

Comment: @JulieHou That's different HTML with different structure. You need to use `print(soup.select_one('div span').text.strip())` to print your <span>. Please edit your question, to not confuse anybody.